# How to measure a LearnedDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, machine-learning, distributions

I would like to measure the qualities of a `LearnedDistribution` in general and with regard to test sets. The docs say that it takes an option ValidationSet, but there's no information about it displayed that I can see:

[image]

*Are there any analogs of `PredictorMeasurements` for distributions,* and if not, any preferred ways of measuring/visualizing goodness-of-fits and other generic stats?

Other than Loss and Entropy that `Information` gives, I don't see any examples of comparing/inspecting/validating these objects once they are constructed.